# Can't see any craft/app folder

Tags: installation

It looks like the craft/app folder is no longer in the Craft download.

I've been using v.3.0.9 from the site and through composer.

Or am I missing something here?

This is causing a bit of trouble with step 4 in the install process:

> Download the latest version of Craft from [craftcms.com](https://craftcms.com), and copy its craft/app/ folder into happylager/craft/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm inferring from that last line that you're trying to install the [Happy Lager](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager) demo.

However, that demo is currently *only compatible with Craft 2*.

The `app` folder was removed in Craft 3. And the demo has not yet been updated for Craft 3.

So if you really want to play with the Happy Lager demo, you'll need to download Craft 2. Or visit [demo.craftcms.com](https://demo.craftcms.com/), which will spin up a full copy of the demo for you.